# Emailing username

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

So I have a column set up for a people picker.  The person searches his username and selects the correct one.  I have an email workflow setup so when the appropriate parties are emailed his username will appear in the email.  The issue is i get different characters such as School-sso-member  lastname%2cfirstname (username).  How can i set it so that just the username appears or the name when the email reaches the persons inbox?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some additional detail? I'm not sure if this is a Visual Studio workflow or a SharePoint designer workflow. Also, what sort of authentication are you using? Windows AD? Is the SharePoint Foundation or Standard/Enterprise? If it's Standard/Enterprise do you have the user profile installed/configured/running?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a SharePoint Designer workflow, you can choose to get the display name out of the people picker field instead of the login name.